# Java: misunderstanding generics and wildcards

Tags: java, generics, extends

Consider the following code:

```
public final class Algorithm {
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
        T max(List<? extends T> list, int begin, int end)
    {
            // ...
    }
}
```

Is the `List<? extends T> list` parameter declaration equal to `List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a very slight difference.

`List<? extends T>` means

> a `List` of objects of an unknown type that is either `T` or a subclsss of `T`

`List<? extends Comparable<? super T>>` means

> a `List` of objects of an unknown type that is either `Comparable<? super T>` or an implementation of `Comparable<? super T>`.

Let's consider this class hierarchy: `A` and `B` are unrelated classes that both implement `Comparable<A>` and are both final. Yes, I know this situation is contrived.

If, from the return value, `T` is inferred to be `A`, you can only pass a `List<A>` to a parameter of type `List<? extends T>`. However, you can pass a `List<A>`, as well a `List<B>` to a parameter of type `List<? extends Comparable<? super T>>`.

Here is an example demonstrating my point:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<A> aList = Collections.singletonList(new A());
    List<B> bList = Collections.singletonList(new B());
    A a = f(aList);
    A b = f(bList); // doesn't compile
    A c = g(bList);
    A d = g(bList);
}

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T f(List<? extends T> list) {
    return null;
}

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T g(List<? extends Comparable<? super T>> list) {
    return null;
}

final class A implements Comparable<A> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(A o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
final class B implements Comparable<A> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(A o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In reality though, very rarely do things like `class B implements Comparable<A>` happen, ***so for the most part***, the two types in question are the same.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. But in my example 'list' is only the parameter the type T can be inferred from, isn't it? So, is there any kind of argument that we can pass to param with 'extends T', but not can pass to param with 'Comparable'?

Comment: You can provide type arguments explicitly, like `Algorithm.<B>max(...);`, in which case they are not inferred at all.

Comment: "But in my example 'list' is only the parameter the type T can be inferred from" Type parameters can also be inferred from the return value. See also the code example I added in the edit. @user3514538